# The first code here does not run through the calculations. Run-time error

Tags: java, time, return

Need some help, it should compute the calculations and return the desired value. Instead it returns a zero.

```
public class TipCalc {

    int satisfactionRating;
    double tip;

    public TipCalc(int satisfactionRating) {

    }

    public double calcTip(double bill) {

        if (satisfactionRating==1) {
            tip = bill*0.20;
        }
        if (satisfactionRating==2) {
            tip = bill*0.15;
        }
        if (satisfactionRating==3) {
            tip = bill*0.10;
        }
        return tip;
    }
}
```

////////////////////////////////TESTER CLASS//////////////////////////////////

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class tiptester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please put in the total cost of your meal "); 
        double mealPrice = input.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Please input your satisfaction rating ");  
        int satisfaction = input.nextInt();
        TipCalc meal = new TipCalc(satisfaction);
        double tipz = meal.calcTip(mealPrice);
        double totalMeal = tipz+mealPrice;
        System.out.println("The tip is " + tipz);
        System.out.println("The cost of the meal is " + mealPrice);
        System.out.println("The total cost is " + totalMeal);
    }
}
```

Comment: What inputs are you giving?

Comment: Note: don't use member variables for `int satisfactionRating` and `double tip`. Declare them as a method parameter and local variable respectively.

Comment: you are not assigning the value to `satisfactionRating` which is you are passing to the `TipCalc` class constructor. try this `public TipCalc(int satisfactionRating) {
this.satisfactionRating = satisfactionRating;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the satisfactionRating in the Constructor of TipCalc as below,

```
public TipCalc(int satisfactionRating)
{
    this.satisfactionRating = satisfactionRating;
}
```

Currently as the value of satisfactionRating is not assigned, it defaults to 0 and in-turn none of the if conditions satisfy in the `calcTip()` method, returning 0.

Answer (score 0):

The member variable satisfactionRating is not initialized. You need to assign satisfactionRating a value that you are passing in constructor from Tester class.

```
public TipCalc(int satisfactionRating)
{
    this.satisfactionRating = satisfactionRating
}
```

This should work!

Answer (score 0):

As @Jerin @Khuzi told you did not initialize satisfactionRating in constructor and see the code below, a typical class should look like this:

```
public class TipCalc {
private int satisfactionRating; //should be private, should be accessed using getter and setter methods
private double tip;             //should be private, should be accessed using getter and setter methods

public TipCalc(int satisfactionRating) {
    this.satisfactionRating = satisfactionRating; //This was your actual problem.
}

public double calcTip(double bill) {
    if (satisfactionRating == 1) {
        tip = bill * 0.20;
    }
    if (satisfactionRating == 2) {
        tip = bill * 0.15;
    }
    if (satisfactionRating == 3) {
        tip = bill * 0.10;
    }
    return tip;
}

public int getSatisfactionRating() {
    return satisfactionRating;
}

public void setSatisfactionRating(int satisfactionRating) {
    this.satisfactionRating = satisfactionRating;
}

public double getTip() {
    return tip;
}

public void setTip(double tip) {
    this.tip = tip;
}
}
```